# diff comparison operation in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, momentjs

This is Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258070/user-input-date-comparison-in-javascript-and-moment-js/47258100#47258100) question. I don't know how to compare the diff. For example if the diff equal to greater than 14 days then the text box should be red. if 7 to 13 days it would be yellow and below 6 days it would be green.

code:

```js
function compare() {
 var firstDate = moment($("#date1").val(), "MM-DD-YYYY");
  var secondDate = moment($("#date2").val(), "MM-DD-YYYY");

  console.log(firstDate.inspect(), secondDate.inspect());

  if (firstDate.isValid() && secondDate.isValid()) {
    // you need a validation before using diff function of momentjs
    var diff = Math.abs(firstDate.diff(secondDate, 'days'));
    console.log(diff);
    // you also need to remove all classes before adding new class
    $("#status").removeClass("redBg").removeClass("greenBg").removeClass("yellowBg");
    if (diff => 14) {
      $("#status").addClass('redBg');
    } else if (7 < diff =< 9) {
      $("#status").addClass('greenBg');
    } else if(diff >= 6) {
      $("#status").addClass('yellowBg');
    }
  } else {
    $("#status").addClass('yellowBg');
  }
    
    });
```

```css
.greenBg {
    background: green;
}

.yellowBg {
    background: yellow;
}

.redBg {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.2/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="date1" onchange=/>
<input type="text" id="date2" onchange='compare()'/>
<input  readonly type="text" id="status"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post your sample code.

Comment: please look the "this" hyperlink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User Input Date Comparison in Javascript and moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258070/user-input-date-comparison-in-javascript-and-moment-js)

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst that question was asked by me only. I want to do some opration with diff. so only i asked as a separate one

Comment: It'd be easy for others to answer if you provide sample code, instead of asking them to visit some link.

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a valid condition: `else if(7 < diff =< 9)`, it shoud be `else if(diff > 7 && diff <= 9)`

Comment: Do you get any warning or error when trying to call that function?

Comment: Now I noticed also this part is wrong `if (diff => 14)`, it should be `if (diff >= 14)`, did you even try to look for errors by yourself? These are such a basic things...

Comment: yeah. Sometimes happen like this. Thanks